# Why does Dr. Gonzo tell Hunter S. Thompson to "Get the hell out of LA for at least 48 hours"?

Tags: dialogue, fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas

I am asking about this scene from *Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas*:

Full quote and context:

Hunter S. Thompson has just received orders from his publication's HQ to travel to Las Vegas to report on a motorcycle race. His "attorney", Dr. Gonzo, delivers the following spiel after Thompson gives him the details.

> As your attorney, I advise you to rent a very fast car with no top. And you'll need the cocaine. Tape recorder for special music. Acapulco shirts. **Get the hell out of L.A. for at least 48 hours.** Blows my weekend.

I'm wondering if there's any particular reason for the "get the hell out of L.A. for at least 48 hours" line. Is it to prevent receiving any heat for other illegal activities they plan on partaking in before heading to Vegas?

Answer (score 1):

48 hours is two days. Weekend.

A bit of history of literature. In "catcher in the rye" Holden pretend he have been shot in the stomach. It's a game he plays with himself. Once he played it in restaurant, just as he paid (had to pay?). Similar location to this.

Here Hunter goes into similar game: he pretend he have some secret mission. Gonzo recognize it and also start playing. While at the same time letting Hunter know that they gonna spend weekend in Vegas doing cocaine and having fun.